# I have a filter applied on map, but when I open print layout, the filter isn't applied

Tags: qgis, filter

I have created a print layout, added my legend etc and noticed that the filter I created in the map has not applied to the map in print layout. I can still see points I shouldn't be able to see.
I have refreshed the map, and nothing happens.
I can't see a toggle option as to whether it should be applied.
What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). You also need to register your account.